# gitlab error connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have changed my default ssh port from 22 to 2233 but when I want to clone the project from gitlab by ssh it don't work.

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

EDITED: I also changed 2233 to 22 but it has not changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, `gitlab.com` will always be accessed through port 22 when it comes to SSH: `gitlab.com` does not listen for SSH connection on any other port.

Second, this is a client-side (yours) issue: the port 22 might be blocked (firewall, company policy, ISP, ...)

Try at least to see if an HTTPS clone would work:

```
 git clone https://gitlab.com/<user>/<repo>
```

(Regarding HTTPS, check if you are behind a proxy, here [on Windows for instance](https://superuser.com/q/346372/141))