# Failing to push origin to GitLab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, git-push

Having a hard time learning how to push my Git repository to gitlab.
Currently getting this error:

> ssh: connect to host gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no port 22: Connection timed out
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I (think I) have connected my SSH on the gitlab website. However I did have some issues on that end too, and I'm therefore unsure whether I did everything right. Most notably when asked to enter a passphrase, my cmd would not take any input other than enter, so I guess I don't have one (or one was generated idk.) EDIT: Managed to change my private SSH keys passphrase. When trying to change the public one, it gives bad permissions error.

I have two files in my .ssh folder: "id_ed25519" and "id_ed25519.pub". And on GitLab, my ssh key is registered. But I don't understand whats stopping me from pushing my git testing rep to GitLab...

Comment: are you able to clone the repo? What OS are you using, what directory do you have your ssh keys in (default git looks at is usually /username/.ssh on windows)

Comment: @goku Not able to clone. Error: "remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.
remote: You can generate one at https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/eriskjel/junit-test.git/'". Using Windows. My keys are in /username/.ssh

Comment: @goku I also tried to clone using SSH, instead of HTTPS, and got this error: 
"Cloning into 'junit-test'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810990/gitlab-error-connect-to-host-gitlab-com-port-22-connection-timed-out

Comment: Did you add to the SSH agent on your local client? This is the app that is usually responsible for supplying your keys to the various apis that use them, at least on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, eventually, the issue was regarding my univerisity recently started  using 2FA which meant I could not use HTTPS to connect to GitLab. Therefore I had to use SSH, which I already had set up, but most importantly ***I had to be on the schools network***, either physically or by using a VPN. Fortunataly, I had the VPN, and managed to push my test-project to my project on GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

> when asked to enter a passphrase, my cmd would not take any input other than enter

This may be your terminal *not* showing which or how many characters you type your password.

---

About the SSH timeout: What does [GitLab's connection Verification](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/index.html#verify-that-you-can-connect) output for your GitLab server (probably `ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no`)?

On that page further up, there is also advice on how to set your `~/.ssh/config` file. If your GitLab admins configured a different SSH, please ask them for details, or check their documentation for advice.

Comment: Got this error: 
"debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/eriks/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no [129.241.162.52] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001C294182D20
debug1: connect to address 129.241.162.52 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no port 22: Connection timed out"
For the record - I do not have a config file in \.ssh

Comment: When I try the `-Tvvv` from my machine, I get _only_ the timeout, not the `async io completed with error`.

[This other post](https://superuser.com/questions/1479014/ssh-from-windows-at-my-house-to-school-linux-server) was resolved by admin intervention. Since you are getting a timeout, I would also think that your local admins will know best how to solve this.

Comment: I will try to open dialouge with the admins regarding this, thankyou. Side note: Should I have a config file in my /.ssh?

Comment: @ErikSkjellevik Not necessarily, considering your SSH key pair used a default name. But if the SSH egress is blocked (as it is often the case in a corporate environment, as [I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56815448/6309)), you will have to use an HTTPS URL instead.

Comment: I see, kinda. I have tried cloning and pushing using this HTTPS url "https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/eriskjel/junit-test.git", if that was what you were referring to. This did not work either, however I got a different error: "Cloning into 'junit-test'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.
remote: You can generate one at https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.stud.idi.ntnu.no/eriskjel/junit-test.git/'"